# HDFS Conection type Airflow not availlable in the list

Tags: airflow, hdfs, kubernetes-helm

I'm installing airflow on Openshift using Helm Chart, I made some changes on the docker image to add hdfs connection, I installed this package apache-airflow-providers-apache-hdfs and I checked that the packages exist inside the container, I did the same for spark, but HDFS connection type is not available in the list, what could be the issue ?